# windows Form построение графика

Tags: c++, winforms

Здравствуйте хотел спросить на тему ,как построить график в windows form , на си++ 
я делаю проект по физике на тему поляризация , нужно построить график так чтобы отображалась сначала линейная поляризация, круговая и эллиптическая . Формулы для 
[image: поляризация света] построения , так же я вывел формулу для Еу (чтобы подставлять точки Ех)[image: выведенная формула] спасибо если дочитали до конца ,если можете помочь буду рад услышать предложения.

Comment: Можете начать с изучения этой статьи http://auriss.ru/programms/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2_Windows_Forms_%D1%81_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC_C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    #pragma once
#include"cmath"

namespace polarization {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Chart^  chart1;
    protected:

    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton^  radioButton1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton^  radioButton2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton^  radioButton3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton^  radioButton4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton^  radioButton5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip^  menuStrip1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  информацияToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  оПрограммеToolStripMenuItem;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::ChartArea^  chartArea1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::ChartArea());
            System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Series^  series1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Series());
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(MyForm::typeid));
            this->chart1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Chart());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->radioButton1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
            this->radioButton2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->radioButton3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
            this->radioButton4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
            this->radioButton5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
            this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->menuStrip1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip());
            this->информацияToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->оПрограммеToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->chart1))->BeginInit();
            this->menuStrip1->SuspendLayout();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // chart1
            // 
            this->chart1->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Bottom)
                | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Left)
                | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            chartArea1->Name = L"ChartArea1";
            this->chart1->ChartAreas->Add(chartArea1);
            this->chart1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(96, 26);
            this->chart1->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2);
            this->chart1->Name = L"chart1";
            series1->ChartArea = L"ChartArea1";
            series1->ChartType = System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::SeriesChartType::Line;
            series1->Name = L"1";
            this->chart1->Series->Add(series1);
            this->chart1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(200, 385);
            this->chart1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->chart1->Text = L"График";
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(354, 69);
            this->textBox1->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(94, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(484, 69);
            this->textBox2->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(99, 20);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // radioButton1
            // 
            this->radioButton1->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->radioButton1->AutoSize = true;
            this->radioButton1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(539, 135);
            this->radioButton1->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2);
            this->radioButton1->Name = L"radioButton1";
            this->radioButton1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(33, 17);
            this->radioButton1->TabIndex = 4;
            this->radioButton1->TabStop = true;
            this->radioButton1->Text = L"pi";
            this->radioButton1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->radioButton1->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::radioButton1_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // radioButton2
            // 
            this->radioButton2->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->radioButton2->AutoSize = true;
            this->radioButton2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(435, 135);
            this->radioButton2->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2);
            this->radioButton2->Name = L"radioButton2";
            this->radioButton2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(44, 17);
            this->radioButton2->TabIndex = 5;
            this->radioButton2->TabStop = true;
            this->radioButton2->Text = L"pi/2";
            this->radioButton2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->button1->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"button1.BackgroundImage")));
            this->button1->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::None;
            this->button1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ButtonHighlight;
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(360, 175);
            this->button1->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(223, 44);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 6;
            this->button1->Text = L"Построить ";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->ForeColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ActiveCaptionText;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(416, 108);
            this->label1->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2, 0, 2, 0);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(81, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 7;
            this->label1->Text = L"Разность фаз ";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ActiveCaption;
            this->label2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Arial Rounded MT Bold", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label2->ForeColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ControlText;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(346, 31);
            this->label2->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2, 0, 2, 0);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 18);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 8;
            this->label2->Text = L"Амплитуда по икс";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Arial Rounded MT Bold", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label3->ForeColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ActiveCaptionText;
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(470, 31);
            this->label3->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2, 0, 2, 0);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(140, 18);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 9;
            this->label3->Text = L"Амплитуда по игрек";
            // 
            // radioButton3
            // 
            this->radioButton3->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->radioButton3->AutoSize = true;
            this->radioButton3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(386, 135);
            this->radioButton3->Name = L"radioButton3";
            this->radioButton3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(44, 17);
            this->radioButton3->TabIndex = 10;
            this->radioButton3->TabStop = true;
            this->radioButton3->Text = L"pi/6";
            this->radioButton3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // radioButton4
            // 
            this->radioButton4->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->radioButton4->AutoSize = true;
            this->radioButton4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(484, 135);
            this->radioButton4->Name = L"radioButton4";
            this->radioButton4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(50, 17);
            this->radioButton4->TabIndex = 11;
            this->radioButton4->TabStop = true;
            this->radioButton4->Text = L"5pi/6";
            this->radioButton4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // radioButton5
            // 
            this->radioButton5->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->radioButton5->AutoSize = true;
            this->radioButton5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(349, 135);
            this->radioButton5->Name = L"radioButton5";
            this->radioButton5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(31, 17);
            this->radioButton5->TabIndex = 12;
            this->radioButton5->TabStop = true;
            this->radioButton5->Text = L"0";
            this->radioButton5->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this->textBox3->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Bottom | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
            this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(324, 391);
            this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
            this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(271, 20);
            this->textBox3->TabIndex = 13;
            this->textBox3->Text = L"Разработчик : Жохов Владислав группа МП-15А";
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this->menuStrip1->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(1) { this->информацияToolStripMenuItem });
            this->menuStrip1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
            this->menuStrip1->Name = L"menuStrip1";
            this->menuStrip1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(607, 24);
            this->menuStrip1->TabIndex = 14;
            this->menuStrip1->Text = L"menuStrip1";
            // 
            // информацияToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->информацияToolStripMenuItem->DropDownItems->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(1) { this->оПрограммеToolStripMenuItem });
            this->информацияToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"информацияToolStripMenuItem";
            this->информацияToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(94, 20);
            this->информацияToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"информация ";
            this->информацияToolStripMenuItem->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::информацияToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // оПрограммеToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->оПрограммеToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"оПрограммеToolStripMenuItem";
            this->оПрограммеToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(152, 22);
            this->оПрограммеToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"о программе";
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ActiveCaption;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(607, 417);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->radioButton5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->radioButton4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->radioButton3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->radioButton2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->radioButton1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->chart1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->menuStrip1);
            this->ForeColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ActiveCaptionText;
            this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedSingle;
            this->MainMenuStrip = this->menuStrip1;
            this->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2);
            this->MaximizeBox = false;
            this->MinimizeBox = false;
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"Поляризация ";
            this->TransparencyKey = System::Drawing::Color::Gray;
            this->WindowState = System::Windows::Forms::FormWindowState::Maximized;
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->chart1))->EndInit();
            this->menuStrip1->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->menuStrip1->PerformLayout();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        chart1->Series["1"]->Points->Clear();
        double a1, a2, ex, ey, phi, b;
        a1 = Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
        a2 = Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
        if (radioButton1->Checked == true)
            b = 3.14;//pi

        else if (radioButton2->Checked == true)
            b = 1.57;//pi/2
        else if (radioButton3->Checked == true)
            b = 0.52;//pi/6
        else if (radioButton4->Checked == true)
            b = 2.16;//5pi/6
        else if (radioButton5->Checked == true)
            b = 0;//0
        if (b == 3.14) {
            for (double i = -a1; i < a1; i += 0.1) {
                ey = -i;//linal
                chart1->Series["1"]->Points->AddXY(i, ey);
            }
        }
        if (b == 0) {
            for (double i = -a1; i < a1; i += 0.1) {
                ey = i;//linal
                chart1->Series["1"]->Points->AddXY(i, ey);
            }
        }
        if (( a1 == a2) && b == 1.57){
            for (float i = -a1; i < a1; i += 0.1) {
                ey = a2 * cos(acos(i / a1) - b);//round
                chart1->Series["1"]->Points->AddXY(i, ey);
                chart1->Series["1"]->Points->AddXY(i, -ey);
            }
        }
        if ((a1 != a2) && b == 0.52) {
            for (float i = -a1; i < a1; i += 0.1) {
                ey = a2 * cos(acos(i / a1) - b);
                //1and 3
                    chart1->Series["1"]->Points->AddXY(i, ey);
                    chart1->Series["1"]->Points->AddXY(-i, -ey);

            }
        }
        if ((a1 != a2) && b == 2.16) {
            for (float i = -a1; i < a1; i += 0.1) {
                ey = a2 * cos(acos(i / a1) - b);
                //1and 3
                chart1->Series["1"]->Points->AddXY(i, ey);
                chart1->Series["1"]->Points->AddXY(-i,-ey);

            }
        }

    }


    private: System::Void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
private: System::Void информацияToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    /*About^ab = gcnew About();
    ab->Show();*/
}
}
    ;
}
```